# Converting UTC to local time returns strange result

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime, utc

I have a solution of three projects:

1. Core
2. Outlook Add-In
3. ASP.NET Website

Both, the Outlook Add-In and the Website use the same methods from Core project to get data from SQL Server. When I write my data into database, I convert all `DateTime` values of two tables into UTC time:

```
POLL_START              POLL_END
2013-07-31 12:00:00.000 2013-08-01 12:00:00.000
```

and

```
PICK_DATE
2013-07-31 12:00:48.000
2013-07-31 13:00:12.000
```

When I get the data in my Outlook Add-In, this is the **correct result**:

[image]
[image]

When opening the same in my website, the picks are fine:

[image]

But my start and end time are "broken" - the offset is added, bute the wrong hours are used:

[image]

Here's the code for my converting, that both, Outlook and the website, use:

```
private static void ConvertToLocalTime(POLL item)
{
    item.POLL_START = item.POLL_START.FromUTC();
    item.POLL_END = item.POLL_END.FromUTC();
}

private static void ConvertToLocalTime(PICK pick)
{
    if (pick.PICK_DATE != null) pick.PICK_DATE = ((DateTime)pick.PICK_DATE).FromUTC();
}
```

And the implementation of `DateTime.FromUtc()`:

```
public static DateTime FromUTC(this DateTime value)
{
    var local = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(value, TimeZoneInfo.Utc, local);
}
```

I had the same result with `DateTime.ToLocalTime()`.
Anyone an idea?

**EDIT 1:**

This is how the start and end gets displayed on the website (end with `End` instead of `Start`):

```
var startCell = new TableCell
        {
            Text = String.Format(
                @"<a href='{0}' title='{2}' target='_blank'>{1:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm \U\T\Czzz}</a>",
                    Common.GetTimeAndDateHyperlink(_poll.Start, "Vote Start"),
                    _poll.Start,
                    ConvertToLocalTimeZone),
            CssClass = "InfoContent"
        };
```

And the picks:

```
answerCell = new TableCell
            {
                Text = String.Format(
                    @"<a href='{0}' title='{2}' target='_blank'>{1}</a>",
                        Common.GetTimeAndDateHyperlink(ao.Time, ao.RealAnswer),
                        ao.RealAnswer,
                        ConvertToLocalTimeZone)
            };
```

`ao.RealAnswer` returns the formated DateTime string:

```
return String.Format(WholeTime == true ? "{0:d}" : @"{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm \U\T\Czzz}", Time);
```

Comment: What is the code you are using to display the time on your web page?

Comment: I'm going to guess that the [Kind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind.aspx) property is different between the two.

Comment: @Greg But why does the Outlook Add-In return the correct result, using the same method? Then the picks should be "broken", too. Or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue now. The `DateTime` values for start and end didn't get correctly converted: The values weren't casted to local time.

**The reason**, why the website displayed the time as local time is, that the SQL server stores every `DateTime` value as `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` instead of keeping the *specified* data (e.g. `DateTimeKind.Utc`) during the insert. When reading the data from the server, all Kinds are `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, so the `.ToString()` of `DateTime` uses the local kind. This results into the **UTC time + local UTC offset**.